# Web page Font verification

Tags: selenium, automation, web-testing

Recently our web application font has been changed and it is having around 50 pages.

Is it possible verify the Font Property of a web page using Selenium or any automation tools

Thanks

Comment: Well the font isn't applied to the page, it's applied to the elements within the page. So you'll have to find out what the fonts are applied to first. That is, find out if the entire `body` element has a `font`, or is it set under a CSS class and the `body` element has that `class`?

Comment: in addition to what @Arran said - after you find said elements, you are able to validate different types of properties.  `font-size` `color` `font-family` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would use selenium to visit each page in the app, then take a screenshot and save to a location.Then you could quickly manually assert that the font had changed

I know it is not a fully automated solution but is still easier than manually trawling through